# Unable to type anything in TextFormField when use ObscureText and Validator in the same field

Tags: dart, flutter

Hai i am new in flutter/dart and hopefully you guys can help me on this. I am having this issue when i use `obscureText: true` and `validator:` in a TextFormField somehow i am unable to type anything in that field. Can someone tell me why is this?

```
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage>{

  final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _email;
  String _password;

  void validateAndSave(){

    final form = formKey.currentState;

    if (form.validate()){
      print('Form is valid');
    }else{
      print('Form is invalid');
    }

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Login'),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: new Form(
          key: formKey,
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                new TextFormField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
                  validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Email can\'t be empty' : null,
                  onSaved: (value) => _email = value,
                ),
                new TextFormField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                  obscureText: true,
                  validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Password can\'t be empty' : null,
                  onSaved: (value) => _password = value,
                ),
                new RaisedButton(
                  child: new Text('Login', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
                  onPressed: validateAndSave,
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        )
      );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the above code. 
Anyway as I was testing the above code so Added/replaced few things like a validator class **FieldValidator** and instead of column use ListView etc.

[image: demo]

Check out the code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}

class FieldValidator {
  static String validateEmail(String value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) return 'Email can\'t be empty!';

    Pattern pattern =
        r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';

    RegExp regex = RegExp(pattern);

    if (!regex.hasMatch(value)) {
      return 'Enter Valid Email!';
    }

    return null;
  }

  static String validatePassword(String value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) return 'Password can\'t be empty!';

    if (value.length < 7) {
      return 'Password must be more than 6 charater';
    }

    return null;
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  String _email;
  String _password;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  void validateAndSave() {
    final form = _formKey.currentState;

    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      print('Form is valid $_email $_password');
    } else {
      print('Form is invalid');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Login'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
                validator: FieldValidator.validateEmail,
                onSaved: (value) => _email = value.trim(),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                obscureText: true,
                validator: FieldValidator.validatePassword,
                onSaved: (value) => _password = value.trim(),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Login', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
                onPressed: validateAndSave,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: thanks but change onPressed: validateAndSave, to onPressed: validateAndSave(),

Answer (score 0):

Assigning obscure text from a variable works for me.
`obscureText: _obscurePasswordText`